# dynamoDB unique key-value in map which is not a partition key

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb, schema, dynamodb-queries

Hi I am new to Dynamo DB. I have a scenario where `movies_watched` should be map of unique movies. Is there a way to achieve that instead of reading and checking the map every time when adding a new movie?

I am using node with dynamoDB

```
{
   "user_id":1, // partition key
   "dob":"1991-09-12", // sort key 
   "movies_watched":{
      "1":{
         "movie_name":"twilight",
         "movie_released_year":"1990",
         "movie_genre":"action"
      },
      "2":{
         "movie_name":"harry potter",
         "movie_released_year":"1996",
         "movie_genre":"action"
      },
      "3":{
         "movie_name":"lalaland",
         "movie_released_year":"1998",
         "movie_genre":"action"
      },
      "4":{
         "movie_name":"serendipity",
         "movie_released_year":"1999",
         "movie_genre":"action"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB does not allow you to perform that type of operation on a complex attribute.  You'd need to enforce this sort of logic in your application code.  However, there is an alternative that may work for your use case.

It looks like you're modeling a 1-to-many relationship between a User and movies they've watched.  To do this in a way that lets DynamoDB handle uniqueness for you, consider storing movies within the user partition instead of an attribute.

For example, your User entity has a primary key of PK=user_id and SK=dob.  You can make movie entities with a PK=user_id and SK=movie_name.  Doing this would ensure that a movie is unique within the user partition.